# Undefined index: password Laravel 5.5 - logging

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5

In my database password column name is "new_password".
then when I try to log, it says `Undefined index: password`.
But if password column name is "password" it works properly. I need to use previous column name.

How can I fix this?

```
$credentials = array(
        'user_name'    => Input::get('username'),
        'new_password' => Input::get('password')
);

$user = Auth::attempt($credentials);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: How can i change the default Auth Password field name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374472/laravel-how-can-i-change-the-default-auth-password-field-name)

Answer (score -1):

**Hello, Thisaru**
**If you need to use your password field as new_password**

1) First thing is laravel password field by default set password into your model. So If you change the password as new_password add this line in your Model

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'new_password';
```

**I hope this code help to solve your problem**

Comment: Hi @amit,  I added that code. but it didn't worked..is there anything to do..?