# Laravel auth attempt not working or returning false always?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've been looking all over the place (I checked all the other duplicate questions and answers ), no luck. I don't understand what am I doing wrong, all the values are coming from post, but Auth:attempt keeps on failing/returning false, if I try to implement login manually it won't authenticate as I am expecting, Also do I have to make or use separate methods like for validation, credentials, username ..etc ?

Here is my login Controller > login method

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'usermail'    => 'required|max:255',
            'password'    => 'required_with:usermail',
        ],[
            'password.required_with'  => "The password field is empty."
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()
                        ->route('admin.login')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
        $usermail = $request->get('usermail');
        $password = $request->get('password');
        $remember = $request->get('rememberMe');

        if(filter_var($usermail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $isEmailExist = User::where('user_email',$usermail)->first();
            if($isEmailExist != null){
                if(Auth::attempt([
                        'user_email' => $usermail,
                        'user_pass'  => $password
                ])){
                    return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
                }else{
                    return back()->with([
                        'message'   => '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the email address <strong>'.$usermail.'</strong> is incorrect. <a href="'.route('admin.password.request').'">Lost your password?</a>'
                    ]);   
                }
            }else{
                return back()->with([
                    'message'   => '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid email address.'
                ]);
            }
        }else{
            $isUsernameExist = User::where('user_login',$usermail)->first();
            if($isUsernameExist != null){
                if(Auth::attempt([
                        'user_login' => $usermail,
                        'user_pass'  => $password
                ],$remember)){
                    return redirect()->intended('admin/dashboard');
                }else{
                    return back()->with([
                        'message'   => '<strong>ERROR</strong>: The password you entered for the username <strong>'.$usermail.'</strong> is incorrect. <a href="'.route('admin.password.request').'">Lost your password?</a>'
                    ]);
                }
            }else{
                return back()->with([
                    'message'   => '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username. <a href="'.route('admin.password.request').'">Lost your password?</a>'
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my user migration schema,

```
Schema::create('vw_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('ID');
            $table->string('user_login','60')->unique()->default('');
            $table->string('user_pass');
            $table->string('user_email','100')->unique()->default('');
            $table->rememberToken();
        });
```

Here is how i seed user,

```
User::create([
    'user_login'            => 'admin',
    'user_pass'             => Hash::make("123456"),
    'user_email'            => 'admin@gmail.com',
]);
```

Comment: - Auth::attempt uses the bcrypt, which hash function do you use? Also, check the length of the user_pass field.

Comment: Hash::make("123456")

Comment: It is as default "user_pass"  varchar(191)

Comment: What exactly fails? Validation or login attempt? Did you check Auth::attempt separately by just passing hardcoded correct credentials?

Comment: NO not validation only auth:attempt is not working everything else is working fine and yes i tried hardcoded still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK OK OK,
I made it work, I think in laravel framework we can only create the column name for the password is "password" field in database authentication table.

I updated the following changes:-

- I renamed the **password field name** from migration schema the **"user_pass"** to **"password"**. (Also updated in login controller and user model).
- Added following code into user model:-

  ```
  use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

  class User extends Authenticatable
  {
   use Notifiable;
   ...
  }
  ```

I checked twice to confirm so I revert back it didn't work.

If i make any sense to anyone please let me know and help me understand. 
I've looked into very similar posts like this [Laravel: How can i change the default Auth Password field name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39374472/5928015) 
can I please have a reference book or blog for all the laravel predefined libraries and functions? I know the vendor folder is full of surprises but still, I need more references.

Thank you so much for your time.