# in Laravel HTTP Basic Authentication implementation it uses email for username , how do we change the column to be username?

Tags: laravel, httprequest, laravel-authentication

in `laravel` we can use `Http Basic Authentication` to facilitate user `login` . without having a login page , by attaching `middleware->('auth.basic')` , to the end of the `Route` in `web.php` , but by default it gets email as the username , how may i change it ?
thank you .

```
Route::get('/somePage','Controller@controllerFunction')
->middleware('auth.basic');
```

picture :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gbzE0azW8TfZsvQN7k7ZoG2PIRlo14i6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374472/laravel-how-can-i-change-the-default-auth-password-field-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#http-basic-authentication):

> Once the middleware has been attached to the route, you will
>   automatically be prompted for credentials when accessing the route in
>   your browser. By default, the auth.basic middleware will use the email
>   column on the user record as the "username".

There is a [`handle()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/AuthenticateWithBasicAuth.php#L39) method inside default middleware.

You have to create your own middleware and override `handle()`:

```
namespace app\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth;

class YourBasicAuthMiddleware extends AuthenticateWithBasicAuth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null, $field = null)
    {
        $this->auth->guard($guard)->basic($field ?: 'YOUR_FIELD'); //place here the name of your field

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Than update your `App\Http\Kernel`:

`'auth.basic' => \app\Http\Middleware\YourBasicAuthMiddleware::class,`

Comment: Thanks , wich controller , you mean `LoginController` ?

Comment: @Geco probably.. I don't know where do you handle auth. You've not wrote it in your question.

Comment: no it dosn't work , it dosn't use the functions of LoginController , i don't know where is its methods , and how it functions , laravel documetation also didn't say anything about it .

Comment: pay attention , it is `http basic authentication` , not the default `auth` that is included with the laravel

Comment: i handle `auth` in a `controller` named `LoginController`, I'm pretty efficient at it, but this one, I don't know how this one works!

Comment: and how should i use it after declaring this class ? sorry i don't fully understand middlewares , but i created one and i overrided the handle method , now how should i use it ? thanks in advance

Comment: [Register](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#registering-middleware) you fresh middleware and assign it to routes you need to be protected by basic auth

Comment: Basically you want to change `'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,` to `'auth.basic' => \app\Http\Middleware\YourBasicAuthMiddleware::class,`