# How to customize "email" field in Laravel auth?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-authentication

I'm trying to customize Laravel's authentication fields. I succeeded for the "name" and "password" fields, but not for the "email" field. I still have the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 "email" field unknown in where
>   clause.

I tried to rely on this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374472/laravel-how-can-i-change-the-default-auth-password-field-name), but it didn't work. In `RegisterController,` I changed the `create` function to the following.

```php
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'user_pseudo' => $data['name'],
        'user_email' => $data['email'],
        'usr_mdp' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can you show user model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error could come from the [`unique` validation](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L53) of the email field in the `validation` method. If there's no column name specified it will [use the name of the field as the column name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-unique).

Add the correct column name to the rule in which it's supposed to search for the email and this error should be gone:

**RegisterController.php**

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,user_email'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```