# Chance SQL plain password field to Laravel hash password

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm trying to login in my laravel Application using make:auth package Have a plain text paswword field in my database, and I want to login using this field called vcclave but also having the functions with the regular make:auth package is there a way to make this replacement?[image]

or theres a way to make this field encrypted to make laravel to recognize?

Comment: You have probably heard this before, but it's not a good idea to store a plain text password in a database (even if you are not storing confidential data yourself)! Why do you need them in plain text?

Comment: Wait, so are you trying to migrate your current plain text passwords to become hashed passwords?

Comment: I don't needed to be plain text, but I cannot find the way to hash all the vcclave data in SQL server in the way laravel needs, do you know how to?

Comment: there is a way to use the make:auth modules without using using hash password confirmation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your text I'm assuming that `vcclave`is the column of your passwords. You should definitely try to get rid of plain text password fields in your database. Two options here:

1. Create a new and delete the old column
   You could 1. create a `password` column, read out all the passwords from `vcclave` and save it hashed via [Hash::make](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing#basic-usage) in your new `password` column. After that, you should drop the `vcclave` column but make sure that it's not needed anywhere else.
2. Update values in your existing password column
   Similar to 1. - get all the columns and update each single one via [Hash::make](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing#basic-usage)
3. Change controllers behavior
   Based on your initial question you might also want to change the controllers behavior [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374472/laravel-how-can-i-change-the-default-auth-password-field-name)

Comment: Is there a way to hash them in SQL directly? I mean creating the password column with all the values from vcclave hashed?

Comment: Not that easily I'd say, because Laravel uses Bcrypt and therefore also doesn't allow you to do direct hash-comparisons within MySQL. It always pulls the hashed password and then uses [Hash::check](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing#basic-usage) in order to compare values. That being said you should write a small script. You could put it into a migration, so you can easily deploy this database-side change alongside the other changes in your code.